# soup.find('table'...) returns None; attribute error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know my error is in defining a table with the attribute width=50%, but I'm not sure how to change that or whether width is one of the attributes we can use with soup.find; I've only seen examples of "class" attribute..

```
url = 'http://cornerstone-astrology.com/articles/zodiac_tables.htm'
res = requests.get(url)
src_code = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src_code, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {"width": '50%'})
tableBody = table.find('tbody')
rows = tableBody.find_all('tr')
astroDict = dict()
for row in rows:
    signs = row.find_all('span', {"class":"Sign"}).text.strip()
    deets = row.find_all('span')[2:8].text.strip()
    astroDict[signs] = deets
print(astroDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table = soup.find('table', {'style': "width: 50%"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: thank you! I get this error still though:
 
```
tableBody = table.find('tbody')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Np. The reason that is happening is because, if you printed the output of `table`, you would see that nothing was found that fits your search criterion. Like I said above, I manually inspected the link you provided and are searching from, and there's no table on that page that has a width value of 50%. BeautifulSoup cannot find something if there is nothing to search from. What table exactly are you looking to extract the contents of?

Comment: The first visible table, basically. Here's the prompt we had: "Given an HTML file name (`filename`), search through the corresponding HTML file, returning a dictionary that maps each astrological to sign to a list containing all the remaining data in its corresponding row. You will want to search for the first table with a width of 50% in the html file. The second column in this table contains images, which you will want to exclude from your list of data. Do not include the last column."

Comment: Okay, I took another look, and I see what the problem is. The `width` is not an html attribute, it's a CSS property. You can also skip the tableBody search entirely. Your original code actually would've worked if the result of table wasn't `None`. I've updated my answer above to reflect this, and I would recommend that you edit your question to address this difference.